# what does -itmp flag on sed command do?

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I came across the following in our legacy bash code

```
sed -itmp <something> file.txt
```

Since I did not understand what it does clearly, I tried the following

Here is the content of `file.txt` before running `sed`

```
dummy={my.java.home}
dummy={my_java_home}
```

I run now

```
sed -itmp "s#{my.java.home}#${JAVA_HOME}#g" file.txt
```

After I run this, I get the following

```
dummy=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home
dummy=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I can see how sed replaces. But I fail to understand `sed` replaces both `my_java_home` and `my.java.home` in my original file although I asked it to change only `my.java.home` when issuing `sed` command above.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because dot in your regex matches any charcter not only the literal dot. So i suggest you to escape the dots present in your regex , so that it matches `my.java.home` string only.

```
sed -itmp "s#{my\.java\.home}#${JAVA_HOME}#g" file.txt
```

And you won't actually need a `tmp` parameters.

```
sed -i "s#{my\.java\.home}#${JAVA_HOME}#g" file.txt
```

Comment: would mind giving a line of what the flag `itmp` does ?

Comment: @brainstorm t is a label. But i don't know what actually the `m` and `p` . I think it would work nicely without `tmp` params.

Comment: `-i` called in-place edit which saves the changes made to that file.

Comment: `-itmp` will create a backup of the file with extension as `tmp` before making changes to it.